# How to deal with OpenMP thread pool contention

Tags: multithreading, openmp

I'm working on an application that uses both coarse and fine grained multi-threading. That is, we manage scheduling of large work units on a pool of threads manually, and then within those work units certain functions utilize OpenMP for finer grain multithreading.

We have realized gains by selectively using OpenMP in our costliest loops, but are concerned about creating contention for the OpenMP worker pool as we add OpenMP blocks to cheaper loops. Is there a way to signal to OpenMP that a block of code should use the pool if it is available, and if not it should process the loop serially?

Answer (score 1):

you can use omp_set_num_threads(int) to set no. of threads inside a pool. Then the compiler will try to create a pool of threads if possible and schedule them. if it is not possible to create pool, then it will create as many threads as possible and run others in serial fashion.

[for more info try this link](http://openmp.blogspot.com)

Comment: It is the run-time that creates the threads - not the compiler. If more threads are requested than can be created, then it depends on many factors as outlined by the OpenMP specification. If the ICV dyn-var (which controls the dynamic adjustment of the number of threads) is "false", then it is implementation defined as to what will happen. If dyn-var is "true" then it will get some number of threads and run the region in parallel. Regions will not be run serially unless nested parallelism is turned "off" or not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do what you want by clever use of `omp_get_num_threads`, `omp_set_num_threads`, and `if` and `num_threads` clauses on `parallel` directives.  OpenMP 3.0 also provides `tasks` which might be useful.